# Relating feature importances from latent space to normal space

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I have a large (shape is (3000, 25000)) matrix that i've reduced to a (3000,2) representation using t-SNE/UMAP, and have seen significant increases in performance of classification on this representation. However, I would like to be able to understand the underlying feature importance of the features *not* in the latent space, but the normal space. Is there a way to work backwards from the latent representation and my `feature_importances_` (from my Random Forest built around it) to the underlying features?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "no".  t-SNE works by representing the local neighborhood distances in high-dimensional space and then trying to keep the same neighborhood distances in low dimensional space.  Because it is defined only based on distances, and even more, only the nearby distances, there is no clear mapping between the low dimensional directions and the high dimensional features.

The longer answer is that you might be able to answer this question for a neighborhood in an interactive sense, following something like this:

a) Run t-SNE, get your low dimensional embedding, then 
b) Select a point that you care about and find it's (lowD neighbors) then 
c) Run PCA on the high-dimensional input vectors for those neighbors

The first few components of that PCA will show *locally* which high-D features are most important.

If you try this for many different points and get the same high-D features that are important every time, that suggests that you could just run PCA on your input data to begin with and get a good low-D representation from that.

Good Luck!